# Make a dictionary variable global in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error, global-variables

I have a dictionary variable called:

```
d["button1"]
```

This works fine in something such as:

```
print(d["button1"])
```

However, I am unable to make this variable global by using:

```
global d["button1"]
```

Because I'm getting a syntax error:

```
    global d["button1"]
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this or another way of going about this.

Comment: `global` argument is a variable name, not a value. `d["button1"]` isn't a variable. `d` is a variable. Sounds like XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set d to be global and reference d["button1"]

```
global d
...
d["button1"] =
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem!